# How to get the height of elements when the height of element changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in getting the height of element through jQuery for the elements whose height changes .

The change in height is when the elemnt is loaded and the element is loaded when we scroll to that element .

So waht i am doing at present is i am extracting the height of the element when window is loaded but some elemnts are still not loaded when $(window).load is called . These elements gets loaded after scrolling to the view of these elements before that they have some different height due to which i get the wrong height of the element .

So I have tried  Mutation but this will apply a thread that stops everything .

I have searched for the answer a lot but havent found any solution
So if anyone familiar kindly let me know to solve this

Comment: could you please post some relevant code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Need to use `.on` http://api.jquery.com/on/ for dynamically added elements. Eg. `$(document).on("click",".div",function(){});`

Comment: $(window).load(function(){  ajustDimension()  }        

adjustDimension()
{
 $('element').height($obj.height());
}

Comment: This is waht i am doing when someone will hit a url .

Comment: get the height after the scroll event is triggered

Comment: actually it does not depend on the scroll the element height changes when it comes to view.

Comment: and doinf after the scroll event is problem because if the user hasent scrolled i will not get the height of the rest elements which has to be shown on the above fold

Comment: When you say "the element is loaded when we scroll to that element", what do you mean? If you're loading the element on scroll, how can you scroll to it (before it exists)? So: what are you loading and what is in place before the scroll?

Comment: Actually the element height is different earlier but once we scroll to that element the height compacts or expands .  so i get that previous height but i want the atual height tha changes when we scroll to it .  and this is not for all elements this is for the elements that are below fold

Comment: down vote
accept
i have used a delay function in jquery but i have one more query

i am eager to know that When i am using a delay() function in jquery and the delay is suppose for 5 seconds then when my delay function is excecuting after 5sec does other function will execute in parallel ?

Means can there be condition that applying delay can lead to syncronization error ? beacuse the value i am using in delay can be changed by other function simulatneously can it be possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the scroll event. Make sure you are not triggering the event too many times: check out the underscore method [throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

Use jQuery `.offset` method to determine position of the element in the entire document, and javaScript `.getBoundingClientRect` method to determine position of element on the viewport. Compute whether the element has appeared on the viewport.

Use `clientHeight` or `scrollHeight` to determine the height of the element, according to your requirement.

Comment: down vote
accept
i have used a delay function in jquery but i have one more query

i am eager to know that When i am using a delay() function in jquery and the delay is suppose for 5 seconds then when my delay function is excecuting after 5sec does other function will execute in parallel ?

Means can there be condition that applying delay can lead to syncronization error ? beacuse the value i am using in delay can be changed by other function simulatneously can it be possible ?

Comment: @user3816859, your comment has nothing relevant to my answer.